# On mains AC, why is neutral different from live?

Tags: power, ac

In AC, we have a 50hz 'live' connector rotating from -240 to +240V at 50Hz, right?

As a child, I imagined this is like someone taking a battery out of a flashlight and reversing it 50 times a second.  With a battery reversing, positive becomes negative, and negative becomes positive but AC is NOT equivalent to that

With AC power, there's only ONE live terminal and the other leg (neutral) is always at 0 volts so the voltage on the live leg varies from -240 to +240V and when it's below zero it's sucking, and when it's above it's blowing, but neutral is always at 0V and also always connected to ground.

Is that correct?

Secondly then, if Live and Earth are connected at the panel...how are they different?  How do they have different purposes?

thanks,

Comment: Live and earth better not be connected at the panel! ;)

Comment: @Type1A haha I didn't even notice that, my brain reading what it presumes to be there not what is actually there!

Comment: In a sense, a neutral is formed by connecting one or more live points to earth. However the design of the distribution system determines which point that is. That point is determined in the design of the supply system feeding the main panel.

Comment: Just a note; if you live in a 240VAC country, then the voltage across the mains wires isn't ±240V, it's almost ±340V. The number you hear/read about, 240V, is more of an average (more precisely, it's the [Root Mean Square voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current#Root_mean_square_voltage). The peaks are a factor √2 higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your imaginary flashlight model. Now imagine connecting one of the contacts to the Earth (literally, the ground). What happens to the other contact as you swap the battery, *relative to Earth*? When you have the negative battery terminal connected to your "Earthed" terminal, the other contact must be 1.5V higher, so it is at +1.5V. Now swap the battery so the positive terminal is connected to your Earthed terminal. Now the other contact must be at 1.5 *below* the Earth, so it's at -1.5V. So that contact is swapping between +1.5V and -1.5V. Now imagine this switching is turned into a smooth wave, and you have it gently "rotating" from 1.5V to -1.5V, 50 times a second. This contact is your "Live" wire.

If you don't earth one terminal, you have an isolated supply. There is no live and neutral as such, just two wires where the voltage *between* the two wires is varying. This is sometimes used in a private (e.g. locally generated) supply.

The difference between Neutral and Earth wires is a matter of use. Current flows in the Neutral normally, it is one of the current carrying wires (i.e. your two flashlight contacts). The Earth wire is separately connected to Earth, and does not carry any current normally. If it *does* start carrying current, a fault has occurred in which your Live has connected to the thing it is connected to, like the metal box of a device, and that current signals a circuit breaker to trip. It's not part of the "circuit" and if it does become part of the circuit, something is amiss, so the breaker trips.

Comment: That's great; clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage is a potential DIFFERENCE. 240V AC can mean varying from -240V to 240V but also from 760V to 1240V. It all depends on what reference you pick to be 0V.

For convenience (and safety) in a residential installation 0V is the "earth potential", i.e. you stick a metal rod into the ground, call that potential 0V and measure all voltages relative to that.

The obvious advantage here is that most stuff on the planet (including you, your furniture, water lines, etc.) sit on this potential and that if you touch the neutral wire (which is at the same potential), no current flows and no one gets hurt. You still need to be careful with live wire though.

Answer (score 1):

Out in the street, there are three 240 V 'lives', 120 degrees out of phase with each other, only one of them is brought into your house. Neutral is the common wire for all of the three phases.

Either at your panel, or the distribution transformer, or both, Neutral and Earth will be connected.

The voltage on each live leg varies nominally sinusoidally from +340 V to -340 V. This is described as 240 V RMS, where RMS = root mean square. An AC RMS voltage has the same heating power when applied to a resistor as a DC voltage of the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Neutral is actually a "center point" between two or three live connections. It is the center tap of a transformer winding or the point where three phases are connected together. Grounding that point assures that the highest voltage with respect to ground is considerably less than the voltage between the associated hot terminals.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that, in many instances, the neutral is connected to ground back at the local transformer serving the neighbourhood and at some distance from the house. Consequently there can be a potential difference between your earth and neutral due to currents that flow in the soil. So it is possible to get a shock or spark if you connect local earth to neutral. I have lived in houses where accidentally grounding the neutral would trip the earth leakage circuit breaker.

Answer (score 0):

Really an interesting question. I think you are aware of the voltage and insulation level and sinusoidal form of AC voltage. I will try to explain my view from this perspective. Consider an example of carrying electric power at a voltage level of **288kV peak to peak** (i.e. +/- 144kV or 100kV RMS) using two wires (not a practical case) say Wire-A and Wire-B and none of them is earthed (grounded).

### Case-A

Consider an instance where any one of the wires, say Wire-A (without having any reference) may attain any voltage between 0 to 288kV with respect to earth (ground). Let at this instance Wire-A is at +200kV with respect to earth then Wire-B will be at -88kV. The same thing may happen with Wire-B. **Hence we have to provide insulation sufficient to withstand 288kV for both wires.**

### Case-B

Now consider the case where Wire-A is earthed. Then its voltage will always be zero (with respect to earth/ground) and the voltage of Wire-B will change between +/- 144kV. That means you have to provide insulation sufficient to withstand 144kV and for only one wire.

Obviously complaxities with Case-B are considerably less. AND Thus we are keeping one wire of AC supply at earth potential (zero) and calling it as Neutrla wire and other wire as Phase Wire.